Steam games don`t start
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/mangohud/libMangoHud.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
fsync: up and running.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
[2024-10-13 22:04:08.915] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/wine-explorer.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:08.915] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/media/razanka/9C14667914665674/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Proton 9.0 (Beta)/files/bin/MangoHud.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:08.915] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/wine64-preloader.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:08.915] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:123] parsing config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/MangoHud.conf'
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.052] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/wine-explorer.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.052] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/media/razanka/9C14667914665674/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Proton 9.0 (Beta)/files/bin/MangoHud.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.052] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/wine64-preloader.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.052] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:123] parsing config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/MangoHud.conf'
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.222] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/wine-explorer.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.222] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/media/razanka/9C14667914665674/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Proton 9.0 (Beta)/files/bin/MangoHud.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.222] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/wine64-preloader.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.222] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:123] parsing config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/MangoHud.conf'
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.367] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/wine-explorer.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.367] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/media/razanka/9C14667914665674/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Proton 9.0 (Beta)/files/bin/MangoHud.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.367] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:118] skipping config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/wine64-preloader.conf' [ not found ]
[2024-10-13 22:04:09.367] [MANGOHUD] [info] [config.cpp:123] parsing config: '/home/razanka/.config/MangoHud/MangoHud.conf'
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/tmp/pressure-vessel-libs-8QLPV2/${LIB}/libMangoHud.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
chdir "/media/razanka/9C14667914665674/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/DOOMEternal"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/razanka/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/mangohud/libMangoHud.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/razanka/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/razanka/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/razanka/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/razanka/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Adding process 27216 for gameID 782330
Adding process 27217 for gameID 782330
Adding process 27218 for gameID 782330
Adding process 27219 for gameID 782330
Adding process 27324 for gameID 782330
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.
fsync: up and running.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 1.


More information is needed.

I am trying to run a game from a disk that is shared between my windows and linux. Before, all games started fine, but now when I try to start steam it says that it is starting and after a while it stops starting. When I started Steam through the console, it throws the following error.
This is my system
CPU - i7 13700
GPU - rtx 4080
RAM - 32 GB ddr5

You've not told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using; the starting point to understanding your situation, you've provided no context for your paste, nor told us what app you're trying to start, how and what messages you get.

I am using lastest version of linux mint based on ubuntu

I forgot to say. I am trying to launch games that are installed on the hdd using windows. But before, when I started them like that, everything worked

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)
